# What is the easiest way to import SeatGeek API Data (JSON format) into a flat data frame?

Tags: r, json, api, dataframe, jsonlite

Within R, I've attempted to query the SeatGeek API for a list of venues using jsonlite but continue to run into issues regarding the nested format of the JSON data I'm downloading (i.e. rather than 'location' having a stored value, it is a stored list of 'lat' and 'lon' variables)

What's the easiest way to create a flat data frame with 1 value per cell (rather than a list of multiple values in a single cell)?

Currently, I'm returning a data frame with a list containing the desired value within each cell, rather than just the value itself (typically each list holds a single value, in some situations with more than one value, i.e. location, which contains both latitude and longitude variables).

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)


perpage <- "per_page="
pagenumber <- "page="
pp <- 5000
pn <- 0

ven <- paste("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/venues?", "country=US&", perpage, (pp), "&", pagenumber, (pn+1), "&client_id=NTM2MzE3fDE1NzM4NTExMTAuNzU&client_secret=77264dfa5a0bc99095279fa7b01c223ff994437433c214c8b9a08e6de10fddd6", sep = "")
ven

vpg <- GET("https://api.seatgeek.com/2/venues?country=US&per_page=5000&page=1&client_id=NTM2MzE3fDE1NzM4NTExMTAuNzU&client_secret=77264dfa5a0bc99095279fa7b01c223ff994437433c214c8b9a08e6de10fddd6")

vpgc <- content(vpg)
vpgcv <- (vpgc$venues)


json_file <- sapply(vpgcv, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
  as.data.frame(t(x))
})


venues.dataframe <- as.data.frame(t(json_file))
```

Any help at a more efficient approach to pull this nested data would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reduce()` with `bind_rows()` works:

```
json_file <- Reduce(dplyr::bind_rows, lapply(vpgcv, unlist))
```

EDIT:
Use `bind_rows()` instead of `rbind()` because `rbind()` does not match new rows by column names.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I'm noticing that with null values, I'm seeing data laid into rows improperly (ex. row 3 values of "access_method.created_at" and "access_method.method" are null, and therefore the row is offset by two variables (the "access_method.created_at" and "access_method.method" are showing "address" and "capacity", and so on). Is there a way to account for these null values?

Comment: Sorry! `rbind()` doesn't work in this case, but `dplyr::bind_rows()` does. It also occurred to me that I should have used `unlist` before reducing. The updated answer works for me now.

Comment: THANK YOU! Your updated solution was succinct, and exactly what I needed. Much appreciated!